# .htaccess FileMatch only works over HTTP

Tags: .htaccess, file, http, https

I have a directory protected with a .htaccess file. I needed to add an exception for two files so I added the following:

```
<FilesMatch "^(file-A|file-B)\.php$">
satisfy any
allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

File A worked no problem. File B however remained protected. I tried navigating to the files over HTTP instead of HTTPS. Suddenly both are unprotected. This solves my problem but I'd like to know why, especially since it only affected one file.